# What's "scan column" and why do we name it like this?

Tags: terminology, information-architecture

[image]

What's "scan column" and why do we name it like this?
Why not just call 'left column' or 'right column'?

Comment: is the source of the image http://webstyleguide.com/wsg3/6-page-structure/3-site-design.html ?

Comment: How accepted and well-known is the term 'scan column'?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like a column the user *scans* with her sight, like for example a navigation menu.
Jakob Nielsen said years ago,  in one of his alertboxes about how users read in the web, that *users scan page content* as opposed to fully reading it.
Also, in forms it is recommended to left-align the labels because if they are right-aligned the users cannot *scan* them. In fact, not being able to *scan* it is what makes columns of centered text so horrid.
It refers to rapidly browsing with the sight.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because they are columns that are mainly used to *scan* for information or navigation. They don't provide content.

Example: [this usability site](http://www.usability.gov/articles/newsletter/pubs/032010news.html) has a picture of which areas are mainly read in a site.

But I don't think that those terms are *that* popular. Search for "left scan column" in google will only give you 217 results...

Comment: Looks like it's a free definition made by Lynch/Horton to name the columns. I.e. I heard those columns called "context columns" or mostly it's only one column, displaying additional information related to the main content and/or ads.

Answer (score 1):

As to why they are named *scan columns*, [Web Style Guide Online](http://webstyleguide.com/wsg3/6-page-structure/3-site-design.html) explains:

> "... much as scan columns have been used in print publications for a century or more."

after stating that (scan columns)

> "organize navigation links and other peripheral page elements."